# Prove:$ C_2^2+C_4^2+ C_6^2 + \cdots + C_{2n}^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(4n-1)}{6}$ without induction

Tags: combinatorics

Here are my problems:
For $n \geq 2$ and $n$ is integer. Prove that:$$ C_2^2+C_4^2+ C_6^2 + \cdots + C_{2n}^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(4n-1)}{6}$$

without using induction.

I have tried to calculate:
$$C_2^1+C_2^2+C_3^2+\cdots+C_{2n}^2$$

But it seems to be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried method of finite differences?

Comment: I haven't studied that yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2k}{2}$ combinatorially](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43323/evaluate-sum-k-1n-binom2k2-combinatorially)

Comment: I think it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

By [binomial theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem),

$$\frac{(1+x)^{2n}+ (1-x)^{2n}}{2}= \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom {2n}{2r}x^{2r}$$

Squaring both side, we have :

$$\left(\frac{(1+x)^{2n}+ (1-x)^{2n}}{2}\right)^2= \left(\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom {2n}{2r}x^{2r}\right)\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom {2n}{2r}x^{2n-2r}\right)$$

Can you see that how the coefficient of an appropriate power of $x$ in above product is related to your sum ?