# Convergence of a sum of polynomial

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have just started reading the book "Measure, Integral and Probability" 2nd ed. by Marek Capinski and Ekkehard Kopp.

The book starts out with a discussion on the Riemann Integral, its scope and limitations. An example is given.

The example results in an upper Riemann sum as:

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^n ({2i^2 - i})$

The authors then state that the this sum converges to a value and that this is easily seen.

How can i find the value to which this sum converges?

Comment: There are well known formulas for [sums of powers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html) - you could use these and explicitly evaluate the sum in terms of $n$.

Comment: Have you done a course on basic real - analysis or elementary algebra? If not, I would suggest you to start there, before studying this book.

Comment: yes, i have done those courses. might be something got lost on the way though as it was long time ago. Any more concrete advice would be highly appreciated

Comment: the power sum would have the summing variable as exponent. in the sum provided in the book the summing variable is in the base

Answer (score 0):

I have found a bunch of other posts that deals with related problems.

I still do not want to close mine as duplicate, just highlight the following posts, which can be applied with minor adaptions to solve the problem:

[Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k(k+1)$ combinatorially](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43317/evaluate-sum-limits-k-1n-k2-and-sum-limits-k-1n-kk1-combinatoria)

[Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/prove-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16?noredirect=1&lq=1)